# Microsoft Outlook what Mailbox is this email in?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

When I search my emails, and click on a result (or see an email in the list of results), how can I find out what Mailbox that email is currently inside of?

Just in the website email client.

Answer (score 2):

> how can I find out what Mailbox that email is currently inside of?

This can be done. I am using Outlook 2016 (365).

Open Outlook, search for the email you want, Find it and open the "found" email.

Press Ctrl-Shift-S and the then Advanced Find dialogue opens and shows you the folder (mailbox) containing the "found" email.

See the screen shot below to illustrate this. The email I found for this test is located in the Folder called Software and that is correct.

If you are using Web Outlook, the Search box is at the top left-hand corner of the Outlook Web App window.

**NOTE:**  If you have an advanced need to search (I use Search frequently), you may wish to download Outlook.com mail to Outlook Desktop (keep it in Outlook.com) and use Outlook Desktop for searching. I have Outlook.com and it is not anywhere near as good as Outlook Desktop.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if there's a similar way to do it on the website for outlook?

Comment: Navigate to the top left-hand corner of the Outlook Web App window.  In the Search box above the list of folders, enter your search phrase and then try Ctrl-Shift-F to find.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly does the “what Mailbox” you mentioned here mean? Outlook email folders or different mailbox like shared mailbox?

As I know, in the results displayed on the search list, the email folder will be displayed in the lower right corner of the line of the mail.

[image]

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer.